# Set color properties of citep and citet

Tags: beamer, hyperref, color, natbib, cite-package

I hope you're doing great. I want to set the color properties (for example blue) of the cite command in Beamer (citep and citet) but I don't know how. How can I do it? That is my code.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,t]{beamer}
\definecolor{mikadoyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.77, 0.05}
\definecolor{yaleblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.3, 0.57}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\justifying
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\let\oldcite=\citet
%\let\oldcite=\citep 
%\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{\oldcite{#1}}}
%\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{\oldcite{#1}}}

%\def\@citet#1#2{{\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue!black}[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}}

\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=20pt,text margin right=20pt}

\title[Title 2]{Title}   
\author{Author} 
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\sloppy
{
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{%
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=palette quaternary, fg=palette     quaternary.bg}
}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
%-------------------------START---------------------------- 

\section{Problem definition}
\subsection{Introduction}
\frame{
\citep{Ansari2014} and \citet{Ansari2014}
}



\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{ref_qualify}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You nearly have the answer in the comments to your code, try with this slight modification:

```
\let\oldcitet=\citet
\let\oldcitep=\citep 
\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{\oldcitet{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{\oldcitep{#1}}}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,t]{beamer}

\definecolor{mikadoyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 0.77, 0.05}
\definecolor{yaleblue}{rgb}{0.06, 0.3, 0.57}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{family=\sffamily}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=black}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\justifying
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\let\oldcitet=\citet
\let\oldcitep=\citep 
\renewcommand{\citet}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{\oldcitet{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{\oldcitep{#1}}}

\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=20pt,text margin right=20pt}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\citep{moore:related} and \citet{moore:related}
}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Offtopic:

You don't need

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
```

as beamer already provides these functionalities.

Comment: The command citep works without problems, but citet doesn't work. The ouput I want is: (Ansari et al., 2014) and Ansari et al. (2014), all in blue

Comment: @Mathias See my MWE

Comment: Thank you very much @samcarter. The right way is: oldcitet and oldcitep instead of oldcite. Thanks, it works